# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId()

Tags: android, android-profiler

I just enabled advanced profiling in Android Studio. But my app is crashing after enabling it with following error:

```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:206)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:304)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.<init>(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:49)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.<init>(HttpsURLConnection$.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnectionHelper(HttpURLWrapper.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnection(HttpURLWrapper.java:55)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.createConnection(GraphRequest.java:1407)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(GraphRequest.java:1067)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1155)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1131)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1115)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1090)
    at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:984)
    at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:244)
    at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:52)
    at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am using device with api level 24, version 6.0

Any idea?